# How do I allow multiple people to open my Access database?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-access, sql-server

I have an incredibly simple Access database.  It has one pass-through query and that's it (no tables).  The query simply executes a stored procedure against a SQL Server database to display the results.  There won't be any data saved in the Access database; it will only be used to display the results of stored procedures.

I put the database on a network share.  If I have the Access database open, non of my co-workers are able to open the database to view the data.  They get the error: "Could not lock file".

How can I allow multiple users to open the Access file and view the query results?

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I allow multiple users to open an access database on a network share?

> **Share a database by using a network folder**
>
> The simplest way to share a database is to put it on a shared network folder. Although this is the simplest method, it is also the most limited. Before you consider this method, all the following conditions should be met:
>
> - No more than a few people are expected to use the database at the same time.
> - No Memo fields are present in the database, or if they are, they will not be simultaneously updated by different users.
> - Users do not need to customize the design of the database.
>
> Note   This method is less secure than other methods of sharing a
>   database, because each user has a full copy of the database file,
>   increasing the risk of unauthorized access.
>
> **To share a database by using a network folder**
>
> 1. If one is not already available, set up a shared network folder.
>
>    For help with this step, see the help system for the operating system of the computer that you want to use to share your database. If
>      the shared folder is on a network server, you might need assistance
>      from the network administrator.
> 2. Make sure that Access is set to open in shared mode on all of the users' computers. This is the default setting, but you should
>      check to be sure — if a user opens the database in exclusive mode, it
>      will interfere with others' use of the data. Perform the following
>      procedure on each computer:
>
>    - Start Access.
>    - Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image, and then click Access Options.
>    - In the left pane of the Access Options dialog box, click Advanced.
>    - In the right pane of the Access Options dialog box, in the Advanced section, under Default open mode, select Shared.
>    - Click OK, and then exit Access.
> 3. Copy the database file to the shared folder. After you copy the file, make sure that the file attributes are set to allow read/write
>      access to the database file. Users must have read/write access to use
>      the database.
> 4. On each user's computer, create a shortcut to the database file.
>
>    When you enter the path to the database file in the Target property of the shortcut, use a UNC address instead of a mapped drive
>      letter. For example, instead of F:\sample.accdb, use
>      \computername\shared.accdb.
>
>    Note   This step can also be performed by the users themselves.

Source [Ways to share an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74#bm3)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Like I mentioned in my post, I have the database in a network share.  Only one person is allowed to open the database at a given time.  They get the error: "Could not lock file"

Comment: @Ek0nomik Then you are not opening the database in shared mode.

Comment: @DavidPostill - It seems if I (the creator of the Access database) have it open then nobody else can open it (even though I have my client settings set to open in shared mode).  If someone else has it open then I am still able to open it.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm still having an issue with locking.  I have the .accdb file on a network share.  If other users open the database it seems okay.  But, if I open the database a .laccdb file is produced and the Access database is locked.  My settings are to open in shared mode by default.  Why is it locking when I open it (I was the creator of the file)?

Comment: Please add to your answer the required folder and file permissions as specified here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/lock-files-introduction#the-lock-file-contents

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is asking this question but using OLEDB, it seems "shared mode" is always on due to the existence of an"exclusive" mode:

> **Exclusive** 
>   Used to get exclusive access to the database if you, for
>   instance, want to let the application be able to reset the database
>   password.
>
> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;
>   Mode=Share Exclusive;User Id=admin;Password=;

https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Also this thread has some intersting info about using "mode" https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c90b1166-e5ee-43ff-a49b-9efe9f416475/opening-an-ms-access-database-in-exclusive-mode-using-adonet?forum=adodotnetdataproviders